# What is javascript minification and bundling of files in Magento?

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento-community, jsbundling, js-minification

What is javascript minification and bundling of files in Magento? 
 Should I enable javascript minfication and bundling for my Magento 2 website ?

Comment: Minification is recommended. Don't use bundling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this link [Configuration best practices](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/performance-best-practices/configuration.html)

- Magento recommends that you use third-party tools for minification
  and bundling (like r.js). Magento built-in mechanisms are not optimal
  and are shipped as fallback alternatives.
- **Activating the HTTP2
  protocol can be a good alternative to using JS bundling. The protocol
  provides pretty much the same benefits.**
- We do not recommend using
  deprecated settings like merging JS and CSS files, as they were
  designed only for synchronously-loaded JS in the HEAD section of the
  page. Using this technique can cause bundling and requireJS logic to
  work incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

As per Sohel's comment, **enable the minification** however **bundling is best left disabled** in it's current form.

It puts together all files needed to all pages and so causes a huge JS file which is inefficient. RequireJS will serve just the required JS files reasonably quickly (especially if serving via HTTP2), so a lot of requests but still less to serve to clients in total.

Even the Dev docs recommend against bundling I believe for now:

> "Magento bundling reduces the number of connections per page, but for
> each page request it loads all bundles, even when the requested page
> may only depend on files within one or two of the bundles. Performance
> improves after the browser caches the bundles. But, because the
> browser loads these bundles synchronously, the user’s first visit to a
> Magento storefront could take a while to render and hurt the user
> experience."

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/performance-best-practices/advanced-js-bundling.html

This is from the Performance best practice section of Dev Docs and discusses the advanced options for bundling using RequireJS optimiser etc. These work quite well at improving performance however take a bit more work. Easiest option I have seen is a module called MagePack however other options are available in the form of premium modules I believe.

https://github.com/magesuite/magepack

The other options for bundling is Magento Dev Tools which basically makes the Dev Docs manual bundling easier generating the necessary build.js files.

https://github.com/magento/m2-devtools